# (Symfony 6) How do I get the actual StreamedResponse CSV content?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony 6 Project where I have a repository, which gets populated with objects submitted by user with a form by a button. I have a second button which is currently doing two things: generates a csv file via StreamedResponse and setCallback function, then downloads it on client side; in addition to that it sends an email via SendGrid with the CSV generated, or at least that's what it is supposed to send.

The problem I have is that I am trying to file_put_contents() of the generated CSV into a file in a project directory.

ProductsController.php

```
private $em;
private $productRepository;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, ProductRepository $productRepository)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

 #[Route('/products/csv', name: 'csv')]
    public function gen_csv(): Response {

        $products = $this->productRepository->findAll();
        
        $csv = new StreamedResponse();
        $csv->setCallback(
            function() use ($products) {
                $handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
                $row = array(
                    "SKU", 'Name', 'Brand', 'Description', 'Stock', 'Price', 'Width', 'Length', 
                    'Height', 'Weight', 'Main Image', 'Alt Image 1', 'Alt Image 2', 'Alt Image 3',
                    'Alt Image 4', 'Alt Image 5', 'Alt Image 6', 'Alt Image 7'
                );
                fputcsv($handle, $row);
                foreach($products as $detail) {
                    $row = array();
                    $row[] = $detail->getSKU();
                    $row[] = $detail->getName();
                    $row[] = $detail->getBrand();
                    $row[] = $detail->getDescription();
                    $row[] = $detail->getStock();
                    $row[] = $detail->getPrice();
                    $row[] = $detail->getWidth();
                    $row[] = $detail->getLength();
                    $row[] = $detail->getHeight();
                    $row[] = $detail->getWeight();
                    $row[] = $detail->getMain();
                    $row[] = $detail->getAlt1();
                    $row[] = $detail->getAlt2();
                    $row[] = $detail->getAlt3();
                    $row[] = $detail->getAlt4();
                    $row[] = $detail->getAlt5();
                    $row[] = $detail->getAlt6();
                    $row[] = $detail->getAlt7();
                    fputcsv($handle, $row);
                }
                fclose($handle);
                
            }
            
        );
        
        $csv->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
        $csv->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="products.csv"');
        
        $projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
        $absolutePath = $projectDir . '/public/products.csv';

        file_put_contents($absolutePath, $csv->sendContent());

        $from = 'mysendgrid@email.com';
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from($from)
            ->to('recipient@email.com')
            ->subject('Generated CSV')
            ->text('Here is the CSV')
            ->addPart(new DataPart(new File($absolutePath, 'products.csv', 'application/csv')));

        $transport = Transport::fromDsn($this->getParameter('app.mailer_dsn'));
        

        $mailer = new Mailer($transport);
        $mailer->send($email);
 
        //for now its download here
        return $csv;
```

The client side download of the generated CSV is what I needed in the prior version of the project, works correctly by generating CSV with the relevant column names and all the entity objects retrieved by entity getters, and is still here for testing purposes.

The email send works correctly but the content of the sent CSV is as follows:
[emailed CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dK7N.png)

I am new in using Symfony but what I think is happening is it emails the actual StreamedResponse as opposed to the content of the generated CSV, which I am guessing is inside $handle within the setCallback() function. The second parameter of file_put_contents() that I currently have is the $csv->sendContent() method of the StreamedResponse class, I have previously tried just passing $csv itself with the same result. I don't suppose I am able to pass $handle by reference since its a local function variable, but what exactly should be the second parameter of file_put_contents() so that I can put and send the actual content of the generated CSV?

Comment: so ... why do you use a streamed response, which usually only can be returned once (streamed) and not just a proper file? or is it too obvious? don't understand why you want to bend something into a shape it's not supposed to have...